# Discord.js voiceStateUpdate Client Voice Channel Not Updating When Bot Is Moved Or Disconnected?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm using the voiceStateUpdate event to keep track of which voice channel my discord bot is playing music in. If the bot is left alone for 5 minutes, it should disconnect and destroy the music player. This has *mostly* worked for the longest time.

Recently, a moderator *Disconnected* the bot from the voice channel. I noticed the bot continued to post it was playing new songs. After testing, I found not only *Disconnecting* the bot causes this, but dragging the bot to a new channel does too.

With some console logging, I found that dragging the bot to a new channel, does **not** update the void channel ID. *Disconnecting* the bot from the voice channel shows as the bot "moved" channels, yet, the voice channel ID is the same.

```js
const { getVoiceConnection } = require('@discordjs/voice');

module.exports = (client, voiceStateStart, voiceStateEnd) => {
    const startChannel = voiceStateStart.channelId;
    const endChannel = voiceStateEnd.channelId;
    const guildID = voiceStateEnd.guild.id;

    if (!startChannel && endChannel) {                              //If user joins a channel
        if (voiceStateEnd.id == client.user.id) {                   //If the user is the bot
            console.log(`Bot join: ${startChannel}\n${endChannel}`)
            if (!channelFind(endChannel))                           //Check if VC is in voiceChannels array
                voiceChannels.push({ channelID: endChannel, users: getSize(client, endChannel) }); //Push VC to voiceChannels array
        } else {                                                    //If user is not the bot
            console.log(`User join: \n${startChannel}\n${endChannel}`)
            if (channelFind(endChannel))                            //Check if joined VC is in voiceChannels array
                channelFind(endChannel).users += 1;                 //Update user count
        }
    } else if (startChannel && !endChannel) {                       //If user disconnects
        if (voiceStateStart.id == client.user.id) {                 //If the user is the bot
            console.log(`Bot left: \n${startChannel}\n${endChannel}`)
            const player = client.music.players.get(guildID);       //Find guild player
            if (player) client.music.players.get(guildID).destroy();//Destroy player
            if (channelFind(startChannel))                          //Check if VC is in voiceChannels array
                channelsSplice(startChannel)                        //Splice out VC from voiceChannels array                                                
        } else {
            console.log(`User left: \n${startChannel}\n${endChannel}`)
            if (channelFind(startChannel))                          //Check if VC is in voiceChannels array
                channelFind(startChannel).users -= 1;               //Update user count
        }
    } else if (startChannel && endChannel) {                        //If user moves
        if (voiceStateStart.id == client.user.id && startChannel) { //If the user is the bot
            const player = client.music.players.get(guildID);       //Find guild player
            if (player && !player.playing)                          //If player is paused
                player.pause(player.playing);                       //Resume player
            if (channelFind(startChannel)) {                        //Check if VC is in voiceChannels array
                console.log(`Bot moved: \n${startChannel}\n${endChannel}`);
                channelsSplice(startChannel);                       //Splice out VC from voiceChannels array
            }
            voiceChannels.push({ channelID: endChannel, users: getSize(client, endChannel) })//Push VC to voiceChannels array
        } else {                                                    //Update user count on both start and end channel
            console.log(`User moved: \n${startChannel}\n${endChannel}`);
            if (channelFind(startChannel))
                channelFind(startChannel).users = getSize(client, startChannel);//Update startChannel user count in voiceChannels array
            else if (channelFind(endChannel))
                channelFind(endChannel).users = getSize(client, endChannel);    //Update endChannel user count in voiceChannels array
        }
    }
    checkUsers(client); //Start check for if bot is left inactive
}

//Get size of voice channel
function getSize(client, channel) {
    if (client.channels.cache.get(channel)) {
        return client.channels.cache.get(channel).members.size;
    } else return 0;
}

//Find voice channel in voiceChannels array
function channelFind(channelID) {
    return voiceChannels.filter(channel => channel.channelID == channelID)
}

//Remove voice channel from Channels array
function channelsSplice(channelID) {
    voiceChannels.splice(voiceChannels.findIndex(channel => channel.channelID === channelID), 1)
}

//Check for if 0 user
function checkUsers(client) {
    voiceChannels.forEach(channel => {
        if (channel.users <= 1)
            checkDisconnect(client, channel.channelID);
    });
}

//Recheck after interval for 0 users, if user joins back, restart time, else disconnect bot and player
function checkDisconnect(client, channelID) {
    let disconnectChannel = setTimeout(() => {
        clearInterval(intervalCheck);
        disconnect(client, channelID);
    }, 300000); //5 minutes == 300000
    let intervalCheck = setInterval(() => {
        var size = getSize(client, channelID)
        if (size > 1) {
            clearInterval(intervalCheck);
            clearTimeout(disconnectChannel)
        }
    }, 1000);
}

//Disconnect bot and player
function disconnect(client, channelID) {
    if (voiceChannels.filter(channel => channel.channelID == channelID)) {
        if (voiceChannels.filter(channel => channel.channelID == channelID).users <= 1) {
            const player = client.music.players.get(guildID);
            if (player) client.music.players.get(guildID).destroy();
            else getVoiceConnection(guildID).disconnect();
            if (channelsSome(channelID)) channelsSplice(channelID)
        }
    }
}
```

```
User join: 
null - Start Channel ID
1025940884321206302 - End Channel ID
Bot join: null - Start Channel ID
1025940884321206302 - End Channel ID
User moved: 
1025940884321206302 - Start Channel ID
1026191047937773690 - End Channel ID
Bot moved: 
1025940884321206302 - Start Channel ID
1025940884321206302 - End Channel ID
User moved: 
1026191047937773690 - Start Channel ID
1025940884321206302 - End Channel ID
Bot moved: 
1025940884321206302 - Start Channel ID
1025940884321206302 - End Channel ID
User left: 
1025940884321206302 - Start Channel ID
null - End Channel ID
Bot moved: 
1025940884321206302 - Start Channel ID
1025940884321206302 - End Channel ID
```

Actions from above logging:

```
User joins VC
Bot joins VC
User moves VC
Bot dragged into VC (first error, no voice channel ID change)
User moves VC
Bot dragged into VC (second error, no voice channel ID change)
User disconnects VC
Bot disconnected from VC (third error, End Channel ID should be null)
```

Comment: Using the erela.js Manage#playerMove event also shows no change in voice channel  ID, even though the even was in fact fired. Log: https://pastebin.com/Wie5BzkT

Answer (score 0):

Oddly, I have never seen this before.. `package.json` was showing I was on the latest erela.js version `^2.4.0` (something I kept making sure of, as I had seen many bugs similar, but fixed with newer versions). After digging, somehow the package installation corrupted. Duplicate files, new code/files and outdated code/files... A simple deletion of the `node-modules` folder and clean `npm install` fixed this issue.